# Ubuntu 11.04 "The destination is read-only" - thumbdrive - GNOME error?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, gnome, nautilus, fstab

I have Ubuntu 12.04.
My problem is, I can't get write access to any USB device, like thumbdrive, SD card or digital camera using GNOME 3.4.1.

Both FAT32 and NTFS filesystems won't work.

From terminal I can create files without any problems...

But when I do this same from GNOME file explorer:  "The destination is read-only":

[image: Error]
[<sup>Link to full-size image</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66rbH.png)

syslog:

```
Jul  1 21:52:48 alan-OEM kernel: [19186.444270] usb 1-5.1: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
Jul  1 21:52:48 alan-OEM kernel: [19186.539012] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-5.1:1.0
Jul  1 21:52:49 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.543752] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9407 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Jul  1 21:52:49 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.546942] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.769766] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] 15523840 512-byte logical blocks: (7.94 GB/7.40 GiB)
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.770881] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.770885] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.771900] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page present
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.771905] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.776387] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page present
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.776392] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.779555]  sdd: sdd1
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.784891] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page present
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.784896] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul  1 21:52:50 alan-OEM kernel: [19187.784900] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

/etc/mtab:

```
/dev/sdd1 /media/CC2A-FA36 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks 0 0
root@alan-OEM:/etc#
```

And /media:

```
root@alan-OEM:/media# ls -l
total 12
drwx------ 26 alan alan 8192 sty  1  1970 CC2A-FA36
```

("alan" is my account.)
It looks like like I have read-write-execute.

So from terminal:

```
alan@alan-OEM:/media/CC2A-FA36$ mkdir zzz
alan@alan-OEM:/media/CC2A-FA36$ mkdir zzzz


drwx------  2 alan alan     4096 lip  1 22:49 zzz
drwx------  2 alan alan     4096 lip  1 22:49 zzzz
```

Work great... but from GNOME I can't....
It's making me crazy...

Comment: What do you mean by `from gnome i can't`. What is gnome? Do you mean Nautilus?

Comment: Can you create both files and directories from the terminal, and neither from Nautilus?  I see the dmask specified but no fmask.  But I have no idea why you can do something from terminal but not nautilus, unless you are root in one and yourself in the other (I do see some prompts show you as root).

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue with 14.04! All I wanted to do was copy a single file onto my thumbdrive. Luckily this question mentioned that it works in the terminal so I that's what I ended up doing.

Apparently it's still an open bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in 12.04 LTS because of an outdated version of Nautilus. I solved using an update and dist-upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
nautilus -q
```

Hope it helps.